# How can I execute more a command based on the Button that called it? (Classes and tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am teaching myself Python and am currently working on my first project. I am making a calculator application in Python which I am calling Pythulator. I am trying to figure out how to concatenate the number pad's respective number to a number string whenever the button is pressed. I created a class called numpad that stores my number pad, and I got it to display on the GUI, but whenever I press a number on the number pad, nothing is printed in the console.
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

"""Pythulator Version 1.0.0"""

import math
import tkinter as tk
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

numstring = ""

class Numpad:
    global numstring

    def __init__(self, master):
        num_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        num_frame.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM)
        self.numpad_1 = tk.Button(num_frame, text = "1", command = self.concat)
        self.numpad_1.grid(row = 6, column = 3)
        self.numpad_2 = tk.Button(num_frame, text = "2", command = self.concat)
        self.numpad_2.grid(row = 6, column = 4)
        self.numpad_3 = tk.Button(num_frame, text = "3", command = self.concat)
        self.numpad_3.grid(row = 6, column = 5)
        self.numpad_4 = tk.Button(num_frame, text = "4", command = self.concat)
        self.numpad_4.grid(row = 5, column = 3)
        self.numpad_5 = tk.Button(num_frame, text = "5", command = self.concat)
        self.numpad_5.grid(row = 5, column = 4)
        self.numpad_6 = tk.Button(num_frame, text = "6", command = self.concat)
        self.numpad_6.grid(row = 5, column = 5)
        self.numpad_7 = tk.Button(num_frame, text = "7", command = self.concat)
        self.numpad_7.grid(row = 4, column = 3)
        self.numpad_8 = tk.Button(num_frame, text = "8", command = self.concat)
        self.numpad_8.grid(row = 4, column = 4)
        self.numpad_9 = tk.Button(num_frame, text = "9", command = self.concat)
        self.numpad_9.grid(row = 4, column = 5)
        self.numpad_0 = tk.Button(num_frame, text = "0", command = self.concat)
        self.numpad_0.grid(row = 7, column = 4)

    def concat(self):
        self = str(self)
        numstring.join(self)
        print(numstring)



root = tk.Tk()

obj = Numpad(root)

root.geometry("400x400")
root.mainloop()
```

I'm thinking the reason nothing prints in the console when I press one of the number pad buttons, when it calls the `concat` function, there is nothing to concatenate since the variable isn't equivalent to a string. Is there anyway I could assign each button a string to concatenate? I tried creating a function in the class for each number pad button that assigns it a string, but that took up far too much space and I only want to do it with one or two functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is highly problematic:

```
def concat(self):
    self = str(self)
    numstring.join(self)
    print(numstring)
```

You have not defined `__str__` so `str(self)` is going to be some funky string.  Then `numstring.join(self)` is a no-operation -- it returns a string you're not assigning to anything at all!  So you're always printing the empty `numstring` you started with.

And -- nowhere are you taking into account **which** key has been pressed... **any** keypress triggers exactly the same `self.concat` call, no info left about "which key was it again?".

`functools.partial` lets you bind arguments in advance (yes, you **could** do with a bedraggled lambda, but, you'll be a **much** happier camper if you forget about `lambda`'s existence...).

So for example one button should be...:

```
self.numpad_1 = tk.Button(num_frame, text='1',
    command=functools.partial(self.concat, '1'))
```

and similarly for the others.

Now, the `concat` method will receive the text corresponding to the button that was clicked and of course it needs to record it somewhere.

I'd recommend eschewing globals and instead starting the `__init__` with

```
self.nums = []
```

Now `concat` has an easy life:

```
def concat(self, digit):
    self.nums.append(digit)
    print(''.join(self.nums))
```

Incidentally, this lets you far more easily implement key features such as a delete key -- it just needs to drop the last item of the `self.nums` list (`self.nums.pop()` will suffice) and it's crucial to let the user correct a typo!

Comment: Thank you! I will try both yours and the other participant's suggestions! Why do you discourage the use of `lambda`?

Comment: @DorianDore, `lambda`, long story -- terrible keyword, too-limited syntax, geekish when Python is really 99% focus on "fitting your brain".  I've seen and fixed more bugs related to mis-use of `lambda` than ANY other Python feature, over 15+ years of Python guru-hood now across many media.  I had convinced Guido to remove it in Python 3... and then he got fierce pushback from the CS-y `lambda` lovers and didn't stand his grouns... which I'm still bitter about.

Comment: I see you've chosen to accept the answer using two of Python's worst features -- `lambda` and `global`.  Best of luck going forward, but remember: when you next hit a brick-wall in your Python progress, it's more likely than not that you'll have brought it on yourself -- by using the worst features, the most bug-prone ones, rather than following the advice of those of us who live and breathe Python and have for 15+ years now, and using the **best** that Python can offer you.

Comment: Ah... I see, well, it happened to work well in the scenario when I needed it, but now that you let me know, I will try and stay away from it.

Comment: I would listen to @AlexMartelli. As a member of the PSF and author http://www.aleax.it/python_mat_en.html , I would stick to following his answers! Just my thought. (hint: accept and follow his answer; yes, lambda is terrible)

Comment: I have one more question. I got a error and was reading through the traceback. I noticed something in the traceback called `limbda`. What's the difference between `limbda` and `lambda`? Is `limbda` better than `lambda`?

Comment: @DorianDore, Python has no keyword nor built-in called `limbda` -- somebody must have named an identifier that way.

Comment: When I tried replacing the `lambda` with `functools.partial` I received the `NameError`  `functools is not defined`

Comment: @DorianDore, then you forgot to `import functools` at the top of your module.  This isn't even Python 101 -- it's something like Python 0.0001 at most.  `import` the standard library modules you're using -- just like e.g in your posted code you `import math` and other stdlib modules (though you actually never use any one of them, which is peculiar too:-).

Comment: Oh, I assumed `functools` was a `tkinter` library, not a completely separate one. Also, I plan to eventually make my application accommodate more advanced functions, that's why `import`ed `math` and `decimal`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lambda` to make another function that call the original method with additional parameter

In addition to that, you need to declare global variable inside the method. To append a string to another string, you can use `+=` operator.

```
class Numpad:
    def __init__(self, master):
        num_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        num_frame.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM)
        self.numpad_1 = tk.Button(num_frame, text="1", command=lambda: self.concat('1'))
        self.numpad_1.grid(row=6, column=3)
        self.numpad_2 = tk.Button(num_frame, text="2", command=lambda: self.concat('2'))
        self.numpad_2.grid(row=6, column=4)
        self.numpad_3 = tk.Button(num_frame, text="3", command=lambda: self.concat('3'))
        self.numpad_3.grid(row=6, column=5)
        self.numpad_4 = tk.Button(num_frame, text="4", command=lambda: self.concat('4'))
        self.numpad_4.grid(row=5, column=3)
        self.numpad_5 = tk.Button(num_frame, text="5", command=lambda: self.concat('5'))
        self.numpad_5.grid(row=5, column=4)
        self.numpad_6 = tk.Button(num_frame, text="6", command=lambda: self.concat('6'))
        self.numpad_6.grid(row=5, column=5)
        self.numpad_7 = tk.Button(num_frame, text="7", command=lambda: self.concat('7'))
        self.numpad_7.grid(row=4, column=3)
        self.numpad_8 = tk.Button(num_frame, text="8", command=lambda: self.concat('8'))
        self.numpad_8.grid(row=4, column=4)
        self.numpad_9 = tk.Button(num_frame, text="9", command=lambda: self.concat('9'))
        self.numpad_9.grid(row=4, column=5)
        self.numpad_0 = tk.Button(num_frame, text="0", command=lambda: self.concat('0'))
        self.numpad_0.grid(row=7, column=4)

    def concat(self, n):
        global numstring
        numstring += n
        print(n, numstring)
```