# functools.partial doesn't pass Tkinter argument

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating an application that requires input from the user. The code has an entry widget, and there is a button that calls a function with the input from one of the entry widgets as an argument. However, whenever I print the argument (the content of the entry widget) I get an empty list instead of what I entered.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import grammar 
import shelve
from functools import partial
from Tkinter import *
def call_response(text):
    print text
    grammar.analyze.analyze(text)

class MainWindow(Tk):
    def new_object(self):
        main_frame = Frame(self)
        bottom_frame = Frame(self)
        main_frame.pack()
        bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        output = Text(main_frame)
        output.pack()
        input_entry = Entry(bottom_frame, width=50)
        input_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        send_input_button = Button(bottom_frame, text='Chat!', command=partial(
             call_response, input_entry.get().split()))
        send_input_button.grid(row=1, column=2)
        mainloop()

root = MainWindow()
root.new_object()
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this to happen, or what might be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fetch the entry *once*, when creating the button; a `partial()` does *not* execute the expressions you used to create the arguments when it itself is called; the `input_entry.get().split()` expression is executed *first*, and the result is passed to the `partial()` object being created.

Use a `lambda` here to have the `entry.get()` executed when the button is clicked:

```
send_input_button = Button(bottom_frame, text='Chat!', command=lambda:
     call_response(input_entry.get().split()))
```

Comment: Ah, I see, The thing is, on a question I asked a while back, I was told to stay as far from lambdas as I possible could, so that's why I wanted to avoid using them.

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996218/how-can-i-execute-more-a-command-based-on-the-button-that-called-it-classes-an

Comment: Having used Python for at least as long as Alex Martelli I don't get his hang-up about lambda, frankly. When you need a closure you need a closure and then a lambda is just simpler.

Comment: Personally I would avoid lambdas here, too. Lambdas are a fine tool for certain problems, but they should be used to solve a certain problem rather than as a standard practice IMHO. I would create a method on the class that the command can call. That method can then get the value and do whatever else it needs to do. In my experience, using a method makes the code easier to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 3):

call_response should be part of the class IMHO which eliminates the problems.

```
    self.input_entry = Entry(bottom_frame, width=50)
    send_input_button = Button(bottom_frame, text='Chat!', command=self.call_response)

def call_response(self):
    text=self.input_entry.get().split()
    grammar.analyze.analyze(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

or just change it to

```
def call_response(text_fn):
    text = text_fn().split()
    print text
    grammar.analyze.analyze(text)
....

      send_input_button = Button(bottom_frame, text='Chat!', command=partial(
         call_response, input_entry.get))
```

as an alternative if you really want to avoid lambda ... but lambda is fine @AlexMarteli has valid criticism of it ... but for something simple like this they work fine